# Product custom options are not displaying at cart page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart, custom-options

I am facing a strange issue with my magento installation is with when i add values for my custom option and click on add to cart the filled custom  values are not displaying with particular product on cart page, although when i edit the cart product and refill the custom option values the options displays properly in the cart i am not getting this because i haven't touch the code for this and never installed a extension who could rewrite the functionality below is my site url for you to check out what is going on

`http://paperhug.instantwebsitecloud.com/`

Also i have checked this on another magento installation where this working fine i am working on C.E. 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is on the product page, not in the cart.
In order to add option data that page needs to submit a form, but the Add to Cart button is just doing a redirect on click

```
onclick="setLocation('http://paperhug.instantwebsitecloud.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3BhcGVyaHVnLmluc3RhbnR3ZWJzaXRlY2xvdWQuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9ncmVldGluZy1jYXJkcy9tb3RoZXJzLWRheS8xLWhvdXItZ3JlZXRpbmctY2FyZHMuaHRtbA,,/product/2/')"
```

should be:

```
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"
```

It may have gotten changed when you were working on the add to cart buttons for the category pages.

Comment: I have added custom option for upload a image buy customer and i want show the image thumbnail on the cart page do you have any idea how can get this working.

Comment: The custom option data is usually a bit split up so the method in this link might might not have everything you need, in which case you'll just need to google around a bit more.
http://www.kathirvel.com/magento-get-the-chosen-configuration-options-of-the-products-in-the-cart/